# Extract Data from multiple objects in JSON variable in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

New to JSON and I am trying to pull information from multiple JSON objects into one table in SQL, below is a small snippet of me declaring the variable:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'{
    "result": {
        "6828": {
            "management_account_id": "6828",
            "management_account_label": "EXC001-00-GP Excellerate Facilities",
            "management_account_code": "EXC001-00-GP"
        },
        "12183": {
            "management_account_id": "12183",
            "management_account_label": "ENF001-04-GP The Zone ",
            "management_account_code": "ENF001-04-GP"
```

I can get the information I need from one object, example below 6828:

```
SELECT *
from OPENJSON(@json, '$.result')
with(
    id nvarchar(50) '$."6828".management_account_id',
    lbl nvarchar(50) '$."6828".management_account_label'
);
```

How would I go about adding 12183 or any other objects I might have to appear in the same column since the fields are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a combination of:

1. `OPENJSON()` with default schema. The result is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type`. The `key` column contains the key of each nested JSON object, the `value` column contains the value of each nested JSON object.
2. `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema (the `WITH` clause) and an additional `APPLY` operator to parse the nested JSON objects from the first `OPEBNJSON()` call using the defined output schema:

```sql
SELECT j2.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.result') j1
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
    id nvarchar(50) '$.management_account_id',
    lbl nvarchar(50) '$.management_account_label'
) j2
```

Result:

```
id    lbl
-----------------------------------------
6828  EXC001-00-GP Excellerate Facilities
12183 ENF001-04-GP The Zone
```